# When i iterate through count, my array changes size, why?

Tags: c#

When I run a simple code designed to make a training and testing data cross-validate, I iterate through each count of my list but each time it iterates the list decreases by 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < adjustedData.Count; i++)
        {
            var tempData = adjustedData;
            var testData = tempData[i].ToArray();
            var trainDataList = tempData;
            trainDataList.RemoveAt(i);
            var trainData = trainDataList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Ah turns out I upvoted the wrong person!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing an element of the array when you call `trainDataList.RemoveAt(i);`.  This is not the same as clearing the value: `trainDataList[i] = null;`;

Let's use a real-world example.  Imagine an array is a series of cups lined up on the table.  When you call `trainDataList.RemoveAt(i);`, you're removing one of the cups.  When you call `trainDataList[i] = null;`, you're leaving the cup there but just dumping out the contents.

Comment: that is the very obvious mistaker i was making thank you for the help!

Comment: But the OP isn't calling `RemoveAt` on `adjustedData`, but `trainDeataList` which is just `adjustedData[i].ToArray()`, so some type of sub sequence in `adjustedData`.

Comment: @juharr No, `trainDataList = tempData` not `trainDataList = testData`

Comment: @roryap Yeah, all those extra variables just make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be cause your code is removing the item from array/list. The below code line

```
       trainDataList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but it's a `for` loop comparing `adjustedData.Count`. Why would removing from `trainDataList` affect that? Is it because it's assigned the value of `adjustedData`, and that removing from `trainDataList` also removes from `adjustedData`?

Comment: Oh actually... Misunderstood. I thought he meant that the loop was decrementing by 1. He just means the `List`, I guess.

Comment: @NickBull, Reference types ... yes since `var trainDataList = tempData;` and `var tempData = adjustedData;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing an item, your array size changes

```
trainDataList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignments:

```
var tempData = adjustedData;
// ...
var trainDataList = tempData;
```

will not clone your list. They will just copy the reference. So you will  have three references to the *same* list.

You can make a (shallow) clone with:

```
var tempData = adjustedData.ToList(); // using Linq
```

Calling `.RemoveAt` on the clone will not affect the original since this time you have references to *different* list instances.